# C initialize pointer to array in array initializator

Tags: c, arrays, initialization

I need to initialize array of this structure:

```
struct a {

   int *a;
   int *b;
   int count;
};
```

My code looks like this;

```
struct a[] = 
{
  {{1,2},{3,4}, 2},
  {{1},{3}, 1}
};
```

This will compile, but segfaults, when program tries to access first element of field.

Comment: Because you haven't allocated memory for the members `a` and `b`.

Comment: This will *not* compile ... This is not valid C at all. Please come back when you have real code that doesn't work. Voting to close.

Comment: I'm with @JensGustedt.  Enable warnings in your compiler and you will immediately see this code is really, really wrong.  `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror` for example.

Answer (score 2):

```
struct a a[] = 
{
  {(int[]){1,2},(int[]){3,4}, 2},
  {(int[]){1},(int[]){3}, 1}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use something like (Adding to BLUEPIXY's answer)

```
static int arr1[] = {1, 2};
static int arr2[] = {3, 4};
static int arr3[] = {1};
static int arr4[] = {3};

struct a a[] = 
{
  {arr1, arr2, 2},
  {arr3, arr4, 1}
};
```

[Live code here](http://ideone.com/nAFZ7l)

Further reading: [equivalence of pointers and arrays in C](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrequiv.html)

Comment: `struct a[] = ...`? Really?